# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting an error when trying to run my script. The purpose of my script is to split PDFs based on the bookmarks given to them and move them into specific folders.

However I'm getting this error when trying to read the PDF.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Harry\[Scripts]\013 - [Blackstone Changes]\3. Split Invoice & SuppDocs.py", line 280, in <module>
    split(path, filename)
  File "I:\Harry\[Scripts]\013 - [Blackstone Changes]\3. Split Invoice & SuppDocs.py", line 115, in split
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb'), strict=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

This is my code:

```
  def split(path, filename):
     idx = 1

     name_fmt = 'CD_%s_%s.pdf'

with open('+Split.csv', 'ab') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)

    print os.path.join(path, filename)
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb'), strict=False)

    filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    invoice_folder = os.path.join('+Renamed', 'Invoice')
    sdoc_folder = os.path.join('+Renamed', 'Supporting Docs')


    try:
        os.makedirs(invoice_folder)
    except OSError:
        pass

    try:
        os.makedirs(sdoc_folder)
    except OSError:
        pass

    bookmark_list = list(bookmarks(pdf))

    if not bookmark_list:
        print '\t ->', os.path.join(invoice_folder, filename)
        shutil.copy(
            os.path.join(path, filename),
            os.path.join(invoice_folder, filename)
            )
        return


    errors = find_errors(bookmark_list)
    if errors:
        print >>sys.stderr, os.path.join(path, filename)
        for error in errors:
            print >>sys.stderr, error
        print >>sys.stderr
        return
```

Does anyone have any ideas on **ANYTHING** that might be able to help me?
Also I'm new to Python so try and dumb it down for me! Thanks!

Comment: What is the _full_ error traceback?

Comment: Here's the full traceback error:                                               
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Harry\[Scripts]\013 - [Blackstone Changes]\3. Split Invoice & SuppDocs.py", line 280, in <module>
    split(path, filename)
  File "I:\Harry\[Scripts]\013 - [Blackstone Changes]\3. Split Invoice & SuppDocs.py", line 115, in split
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb'), strict=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Comment: Edit the question with the error. Don't post it in the comments

Comment: There you go :/ Sorry xD

Comment: PdfFileReader doesn't have the strict

Comment: Give some versions info; `PdfFileReader` is documented to have the strict argument https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader

Comment: Just using basic pyPdf.PdfFileReader

Comment: I suspect you are using pyPDF1.3: http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/ but reading docs for pdPDF2: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html

Comment: How do I change my PyPDF version so it matches my code?

Comment: You should install pyPDF2 in the same way you installed pyPDF1.3 - They seems to be different packages.

Comment: I have multiple versions of this script and the others work however this one does not so it cannot be something I have installed it has to be a code error.

Answer (score 0):

Likely cause is based on the error you stated

```
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb'), strict=False)
```

this line shouldn't function doesn't allow the value strict so it should be removed or used elsewhere. For example

```
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb'))
```

Comment: Also, Tried this fix and code has error'd out with something I've never seen before?                                                                                                **PdfReadError: multiple definitions in dictionary**                                                Any thoughts?

Comment: found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602639/pypdf-merge-and-write-issue try it out and see if it helps

Comment: Tried, didn't work just brings back the same error. Could you give me the exact code you think will work if you believe it's defiantly the solution?