# Requests Python and Curl Commands do not work

Tags: python, rest, api

```
import requests

response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/user/repos')
```

Simple code just to test that requests are working.
I get the following errors.

```
\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/2/101_gui/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/2/101_gui/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/user/repos')
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 87, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 279, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 374, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 174, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 417, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 232, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 547, in _new_conn
    strict=self.strict)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am trying to figure out why I cannot at all connect to my bit bucket server, using stashy, using any other lib, even having trouble with calls requests's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works on my machine. 
You should try upgrading the requests module by using pip upgrade.

Comment: Actually? Okay, this might be my problem with a bunch of questions I have been posting, because I am trying to basically convert rest api calls to Python calls, stashy has the same issue. This is all in an attempt to get Python to work with Bit Bucket. So Thank you, but if you could answer me this question it would be forever a learning experience, why am I getting the exact same error with stashy, or atlassian importing Bitbucket. Its been this same error that is plaguing me.This error also spits out immediately, without any "actual timeout"

Comment: @AlehandroTheGreat If you suspect the issue might be related to the library versions you’re using, can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: You guys are correct :) It was the library version, upgrading it solved all issues. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After executing your source code I have no problem executing it accordingly. I think you need to update your request library. Here's how to do that:

https://realpython.com/python-requests/

Comment: How come I am getting the exact same error using Libraries such as Stashy, or Atlassian to connect to Bit Bucket and display even my repos? Anything I seem to attempt seems to spit out this error, I could update requests as you have suggested, but if that does not fix the error, what would be my next steps as I have seen the exact same error message various of times/attempting different methods. Previosuly I was told **TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'** is a key to my error but digging even more deeper I cannot find anything related to my issue.

Comment: I would ask them to specialise the information in the question a little. I may then be able to explain the problem to you in more detail. Which Python version do you currently work with ? Which pip version and which request version do you use? Have you already done an update?

Comment: Maybe this will help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939282/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-strict

Comment: I am currently on a network that blocks pip, I would have to run pip upgrade from my home network, my currently python version is 3.7. I was able to actually run my code on a co-workers machine(s) running python 2.7 and 3.8, and it worked fine, so I am left again scratching my head, but perhaps like you suggested a pip upgrade would work, but no one else has seen the same error I have posted above, which suggests a time out issue without actually trying anything

Comment: You guys are correct :) It was the library version, upgrading it solved all issues. thanks